# Css transition not working with css animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

i have simple animation on div which change background-color on :hover,
but, when mouse leave this div, the transition with initial color is not working

if someone has css or javascript solution it is welcome !

```css
.arc_en_ciel{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(64, 137, 126);

    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.7s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: background-color 0.7s ease-in-out;
    transition: background-color 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.arc_en_ciel:hover{
    animation-name: animation;
    animation-duration: 4s;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;    
    animation-play-state: running;
}
@-webkit-keyframes animation{
    0%     {background-color: rgb(64, 137, 126);}
    50%  {background-color: #1f5e54;}
    100%  {background-color: rgb(64, 137, 126);}
}
@keyframes animation{
    0%     {background-color: rgb(64, 137, 126);}
    50%  {background-color: #1f5e54;}
    100%  {background-color: rgb(64, 137, 126);}
}
```

```html
<div class="arc_en_ciel"></div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Without your HTML, CSS is useless to us. Please read [how to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `animation` is a reserved word in CSS, try renaming your animation something unique.

Comment: Do you mean transition doesn't work when color changing from default to color of animation and vise versa? (your color pallet is so subtle, very hard to see the difference, try more contrast colors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that CSS animation animates the background color, but doesn't change the value.

There is no transition once you stop hovering because the color is the same.

You may get what you're looking for with a simple transition:

```css
.arc_en_ciel{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: rgb(64, 137, 126);
    transition: background-color 0.7s ease-in-out;
}

.arc_en_ciel:hover{
    background-color: #1f5e54;
    transition: background-color 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<div class="arc_en_ciel"></div>
```